# c# Textbox not refreshed itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox and I want to update it's text from my code.
In this example. I have a textbox and a db process function. Before this db process I write the textbox and after the process write textbox again.
The process works well but the textbox not refreshed itself

What i must do ?

This code is not working:

screen side:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lblA" Text="0" runat="server" />
```

code side :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CalcSummary();

// this function doing somethings on DB
MultiplePayrollUndo(lstCemp);

CalcSummary();
}

private void CalcSummary()
{ 
lblA.Text="its a select count result from DB and its correct".ToString();
}
```

Comment: You give  the same text in lblA.Text. Why the end of the lblA.Text added ToString? it is already string.

Answer (score 0):

When Page_Load is running, nothing is displayed immediately.

**You can do it at client-side with interval check and change textbox value by Javascript.**

On process-end add event handler to change Property/flag that indicates, state of the DB process, the page can read.

If You want to run process manualy (by button, link, ...), on PageLoad try to display the first value and after ending DB process, You have to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks you give me an idea

Answer (score 0):

"Vojta Novák" give me an Idea. Thanks.

I change my screen and code like this.
And It runs like what I need.

Screen side:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Panel1" GroupingText="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="lblA" Text="0" runat="server" />
     </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Side :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 CalcSummary();

 // this function doing somethings on DB
 MultiplePayrollUndo(lstCemp);

 CalcSummary();
}

private void CalcSummary()
{ 
lblA.Text="its a select count result from DB and its correct".ToString();
Panel1.Update();
}
```